# Onclick event js not rendering

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I need to render a new card that already has a function with the change event. I was trying to remove a class from the actual card (show) so it wont show the card and then add a class (show) to the oter card that I want to render. I did this code, but it doesnt work, any other ideas? thanks.

```
const dropdownmenucli = () => {
    const print = document.getElementById ('drop2');
    const dropdown= document.getElementById ('dropdowns2');
    
    const printDocument=document.getElementById('cnd');
    const delWindow=document.getElementById('exampleModal2');
    const popWindow=document.getElementById('exampleModal');
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const value = document.getElementById('dropdowns2').value;
        
        
        print.innerHTML=`
            
            <div class="padding-b" >
                <a class="text-decoration btn btn-primary" id="cnd"> Create New Document </a>
                <a class="text-decoration btn btn-primary" href="/Create/${value}"> Existing Document</a>
            </div>
        `
    })
}
const Redirect = document.getElementById('cnd') ? () => {
    printDocument.addEventListener('clik',(event) => {
        delWindow.classList.remove("show");
        popWindow.classList.add("show");
    })
    
}: null

dropdownmenucli()
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: that's not helpful. How do we know what's wrong when all you tell us is "it doesn't work"?